# How do i convert from Task To List in this case?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

I'm getting this error...

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task System.Collections.Generic.List Thoughts.ViewModel.PickerViewModel.Location'** to **'System.Collections.Generic.List Thoughts.ViewModel.PickerViewModel.Location '

Anyone an idea?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace Thoughts.ViewModel
{
    public class PickerViewModel 
    {
        public List<Location> LocationsList { get; set; }

        public class Location
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
        }

        public PickerViewModel()
        {
            LocationsList = GetLocations();
        }

        public async Task<JToken> GoogleApi()
        {
            var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
            string locationString = location.Latitude.ToString() + "," + location.Longitude.ToString();
            string radius = "2000";
            string apiKey = "My_API_KEY";//Ofcourse its filled in


            var httphelper = new HttpClient();
            string link = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + locationString + "&radius=" + radius + "&key=" + apiKey;
            var data = await httphelper.GetStringAsync(link);
            var jsonData = JObject.Parse(data)["results"];
            return jsonData;

        }

        public async Task<List<Location>> GetLocations()
        {
            JToken data = await GoogleApi();
            var locationList = new List<Location>() { };
            foreach (var location in data)
            {
                new Location() {name = location["name"].ToString() };
            }
            return locationList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `LocationsList = GetLocations().Result`?

Comment: You really shouldn't call async code from a constructor.  Maybe instead of a constructor you could have a static method that is async, calls the `GetLocations` with `await` and then initializes the `PickerViewModel ` object and returns it.

Comment: Neither of these answers is a solution for my problem...

Answer (score 1):

A `Task<T>` is a `Task` wrapper around a value. Normally, you would unwrap it using `await`.

However, in this case, the value you're unwrapping is something you want to display in a UI. So here you would want to have your constructor set up something to display in the meantime (an empty collection, or a "Loading..." indicator). Your constructor should then *start* an asynchronous operation that *updates* the data to display. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding) goes into more details on this pattern.